# How to update a AzureGroupDeployment with new values?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring

Used below command to create Azure alerts using the ARM templates .

```
az group deployment create --template-file template.json --parameters parameters.json  --resource-group myrgname
```

This template contains logqueries to create the alert rule and Now I need to modify the previously created alert rule values. I couldnt find any option n to update the existing deployment, So I re-run the same deployment file again with new threshold values.

So would like to understand,

- if we re run the same "az group deploymente create " command with new values, is this just updating the values alone or entire rule is getting deleted and recreated?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your resources using ARM template , you specify that the deployment is either an incremental update or a complete update.

As mentioned in the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#incremental-mode), if you are redeploying the resource using the same ARM template in incremental mode then resource properties will reapplied. The properties aren't incrementally added.

Generally, in Complete mode Resource Manager **deletes** resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.
Always use the [what-if operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if) before deploying a template in complete mode. What-if shows you which resources will be created, deleted, or modified. Use what-if to avoid unintentionally deleting resources. If your template includes a resource that isn't deployed because [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment) evaluates to false